# How to count the number of same innerText in an xml file?

Tags: c#, xml

I try to count and then display how many `innerText` in an xml file are the same. I found this code to count how many equal nodes exists but not how many equal `innerText`.

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(path_to_xml);
var result = from XmlNode n in doc.SelectNodes("//task/*")
             group n by n.InnerText into g
             select new {
                 Text = g.Key,
                 Count = g.Count()
             };
```

For example, I have an xml like this:

```
<rootNode>
    <foo>
        <first>stackoverflow</first>
        <second>stackoverflow</second>
        <third>superuser</third>
    </foo>
</rootNode>
```

Now I should get that result:

```
stackoverflow: Count 2
superuser: Count 1
```

Is there a way to do that? I'm parsing the XML using `XmlDocument`.

Any suggestions? :)

Comment: Looks like this is for InnerText > `group n by n.InnerText into g` ?

Comment: Thats what I thought first but it just counts my nodes

Comment: What do you want otherwise?

Comment: The code above tell me how many nodes called "first" (for example) are there. But I want to know how many `innerText` called "stackoverflow" and "superuser" are in the xml file

Comment: Changed the `SelectNodes` statement to `doc.SelectNodes("//foo/*")` and it does return an anonymous object with Text and Count as expected. Check your code, you might have some other problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be this?

Using Linq to Xml:

```
var result = XDocument.Parse(xml)
    .Descendants("foo")
    .Elements()
    .GroupBy(x => x.Value)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Count());
```

Using XmlDocument:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);

var node = doc.SelectSingleNode("//foo");
var result2 = node.ChildNodes
    .Cast<XmlNode>()
    .GroupBy(x=>x.InnerText)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Count());
```

To show in Messagebox try this:

```
foreach (var pair in result)
{
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} found {1} number of times", pair.Key, pair.Value));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there something for `XmlDocument` as well? :)

Comment: Okay, thanks. If I want to display it (for example a MsgBox), how to do that exactly? I tried `MessageBox.Show(result2.ToString())` but then it (logically) displays me `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2[System.String, System.Int32]`

Comment: It's getting closer :) In my xml I have a node called "<machine>" and in there I have two times "test1" and one time "test2" (like this: `<root><machine>test1</machine></root><root><machine>test2</machine></root><root><machine>test1</machine></root>`). And now I got three MsgBoxes with always this content: "test1 found 1 number of times". But nothing from "test2" it shows nothing... Perhaps you know why? :)

Comment: Simply change this line `SelectSingleNode` to `SelectNodes`. Ex: `var node = doc.SelectNodes("//machine");`

Comment: Then an error occurs. `System.Xml.XmlNodeList does not contain a definition for 'ChildNodes'`

Comment: Just delete the `ChildNodes` `var result2 = node
                .Cast<XmlNode>()
                .GroupBy(x => x.InnerText)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Count());`

Answer (score 0):

For the XML that you pasted it would be like this:

```
var result = from XmlNode n in doc.SelectNodes("/rootNode/foo/*")
             group n by n.InnerText into g
             select new {
                 Text = g.Key,
                 Count = g.Count()
             };
```

make sure that your XPath is correct...

dumping result to console could be like this:

```
result.ToList().ForEach(r => Console.WriteLine( r.Text + ": Count " + r.Count));
```

Comment: And how can I display the number of the counted innerText? For example in a `MessageBox`? :)

Comment: result.ToList().ForEach( r => Console.WriteLine( r.Text + " " + r.Count));